# JavaFX Connect 4 game win method

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a Connect 4 game in JavaFX here is my `checkWin` method. The way my game works is that every cell in `board` has a blank circle in it and only when user chooses a column does it then have `setFill(Color.RED)` (or blue depending on the player). Everything is working fine except this method.

```
public void checkWin(int row, int column, GridPane board) {
        Circle piece = ((Circle)getNodeByRowColumnIndex(row, column, board));

        // Horizontal check
        if (column - 3 <= 0) {
            for(int i = 1; piece.equals((Circle)getNodeByRowColumnIndex(row, column + i, board)) ; i++) {
                System.out.println("Checking : (" + (row) + " , " + (column + i) + ")");
                if(i == 4) hasWon = true;
            }
        } else if (column + 3 > Columns) {
            for(int i = 1; piece.equals((Circle)getNodeByRowColumnIndex(row, column - i, board)) ; i++) {
                System.out.println("Checking : (" + (row) + " , " + (column - i) + ")");
                if(i == 4) hasWon = true;
            }       
        }

        // Vertical check
        if (row - 3 <= 0) {
            for(int i = 1; piece.equals((Circle)getNodeByRowColumnIndex(row + i, column, board)) ; i++) {
                System.out.println("Checking : (" + (row + i) + " , " + (column) + ")");
                if(i == 4) hasWon = true;
                System.out.println(i);
            }

        } else if (row + 3 > Rows) {
            for(int i = 1; piece.equals((Circle)getNodeByRowColumnIndex(row - i, column, board)) ; i++) {
                System.out.println("Checking : (" + (row - i) + " , " + (column) + ")");
                if(i == 4) hasWon = true;
            }       
        }

        // Ascending diagonal check
        if (row - 3 <= 0 && column - 3 <= 0) {
            for(int i = 1; piece.equals((Circle)getNodeByRowColumnIndex(row + i, column + i, board)) ; i++) {
                System.out.println("Checking : (" + (row + i) + " , " + (column + i) + ")");
                if(i == 4) hasWon = true;
            }
        } else if (row + 3 > Rows && column + 3 > Columns) {
            for(int i = 1; piece.equals((Circle)getNodeByRowColumnIndex(row - i, column - i, board)) ; i++) {
                System.out.println("Checking : (" + (row - i) + " , " + (column - i) + ")");
                if(i == 4) hasWon = true;       
            }
        }

        // Descending diagonal check
        if (row + 3 > Rows && column - 3 <= 0) {
            for(int i = 1; piece.equals((Circle)getNodeByRowColumnIndex(row - i, column + i, board)); i++) {
                System.out.println("Checking : (" + (row - i) + " , " + (column + i) + ")");
                if(i == 4) hasWon = true;
            }

        } else if (row - 3 <= 0 && column + 3 > Columns) {
            for(int i = 1; piece.equals((Circle)getNodeByRowColumnIndex(row + i, column - i, board)); i++) {
                System.out.println("Checking : (" + (row + i) + " , " + (column - i) + ")");
                if(i == 4) hasWon = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you could enlighten us, *whats not working* with this code?

Comment: This method is not counting Circles in a row/column/diagonal as it should be

Comment: You're not returning anything from here except via the instance variable hassWon. I would have made this a boolean function and returned true or false directly.

Comment: I tried that, still nothing. It doesn't seem to be iterating through the for loops

Comment: It would help if we could see class Circle.

Answer (score 5):

First, and in general, try to separate your data from your representation. So keep some array or other data structure where you only store if there is a stone and what. **Don't store circles**

Second. The actual problem is closely related and shows why you should do so:
You only want to compare the colors of the circles. Not the circles themselves. 
(I'm only guessing that these are JavaFX Circles because you don't show the complete code...)
Because every circle has a radius and *a center*. And every center is most probable different your equals method will always return false.

So compare only colors. Or better: separate data from representation.